# Android gestures

Tags: android, coordinates

I am new to android.I am making an app in which I want to get all the dynamic coordinates of scroll gesture. e.g if I draw a line I want to get all the coordinates of that line.How to obtain that?

I have tried to take the values in array like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float distanceX,float distanceY) {
   x =me1.getRawX()+me2.getRawX();
   xval.add((int) x);
   return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    onScroll(me,me,x,y);
    Intent i=new Intent();
    i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("key0", xval );
    setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
}
return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
```

This code is able to fetch only the first coordinate of the scroll gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get all the coordinates of the line, its inefficient.  Instead you use the mathematical formula for distance from a point to a line, and see if you're close.  If you're close enough (never expect the user to tap exactly on a line), then that point counts as on the line.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line